# Combining count from one table and distinct from another

Tags: mysql, sql

I've setup a contest where video submissions are sent in and then people vote on them. Submissions are sent into a table `submissions` with this structure:

```
submission_id, title, videoname
```

The voting table `votes` structure is:

```
video_id, voter_id
```

The video_id correlates to the submission_id in the submissions table.

I want to get the number of votes for each video like so:

```
select video_id, count(1) from votes group by submission_id
```

But I also want to display the title for each video so the result would be:

```
video_id, count, title
```

I am a sql noob so please forgive me if this is a simple statement.  I have done some research and was not able to come up with something on my own and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend doing a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`... and `COUNT(v.video_id)` instead of `COUNT(*)`.  This way you will still return submissions that currently have 0 votes:

```
select
  s.submission_id as video_id,
  count(v.video_id) as vote_count,
  s.title
from
  submissions s
  left join votes v on v.video_id = s.submission_id
group by 
  s.submission_id, 
  s.title
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select s.submission_id, s.title, s.videoname, c.cnt
from
submissions s,
(select video_id, count(1) as cnt from votes group by video_id) c
where
s.submission_id = c.video_id
```

Comment: why are you running a subquery rather than a join? I've never seen a query like that before.

Answer (score 0):

This will return every video from you submissions table and show the number of votes in the votes table. If there have not been any votes it will show up in the results with a NULL as the Votes column

```
SELECT video_id, title, COUNT(voter_id) Votes
FROM submissions s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN votes v ON s.submission_id = v.video_id
GROUP BY video_id, title,
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a join for retrieve the votes and the video title, between the two tables like this :

```
SELECT submissions.submission_id
     , COUNT(1)
     , submissions.videoname
FROM submissions LEFT OUTER JOIN votes
    ON votes.video_id = submissions.submission_id
GROUP BY submissions.submission_id, submissions.videoname
```